# Me genera este error:Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"...?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Obtengo el siguiente error al ejecutar el proyecto:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.

Este es el Archivo pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <properties>

  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Mira, te he respondido pero luego he visto que no te molestas en marcar como aceptadas las respuestas que se te dan, y así no funciona este sitio (mira el [help]) . Así que he borrado mi respuesta. Cuando vea que actúas de acuerdo con las normas del sitio ya volveré a hacerla visible. Un saludo.

Comment: SJuan76 disculpa pero no llegue a visualizar su respuesta pero de todas maneras muchas gracias

Comment: A mi me funcion agregando la dependencia de SLF4J pero la versión 1.7.5

Answer (score 1):

te hace falta agregar la dependencia de SLF4J, **junto con las otras.**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

fijate de poner la versión que necesitas, o sacar el tag  si el pon esta configurado para que te la elija automáticamente.

Comment: me sale este mensaje Duplicating managed version 1.7.25 for slf4j-api porque ya se encuentra instalado

Comment: lo he bajado de version <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
  </parent> a 1.3.3 y no me sale el mensaje de error a que se debera de todas formas muchas gracias

Comment: bueno he investigado por diferentes fuentes y mi problema se soluciono cuando elimine lo que contenía la carpeta... /.M2/Repository/   y deje que el IDE de Spring instalara  las librerias y recién me pudo solucionar el error

Answer (score 1):

Mira para solucionarlo adiciona la siguiente librería `slf4j-nop.jar` en el class path de tu aplicación

[Fuente](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)